# En Python, ¿cómo ejecutar otras instrucciones si se finaliza la ejecución del bucle for sin interrupciones?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo a usar `for in` y tengo el siguiente código:

```
oclusivas = ["p","t","k","b","d","g"]
claves = ["zka","ze","apapk"]
si=[]
no=[]
for palabra in claves:
    for caracter in palabra:
        if caracter in oclusivas:
            print(palabra,"--->",caracter)
            si.append(palabra)
            break
print("si: ",si)
print("no: ",no)
```

bueno, al momento de pasarlo por consola:

```
zka ---> k
apapk ---> p
si:  ['zka', 'apapk']
no:  []
```

Se ve que hace print de la palabra y del caracter oclusivo detectado; agregué `break` para que vaya directamente a la siguiente clave y no haya repetidos, pero no logro agregar los que no contienen oclusiva a la lista "no" y he probado usando `if caracter in oclusivas == False` pero no funciona como lo tengo pensado :/

Comment: `not in`, no `if in oclusivas == False`, aunque lo más sencillo sería directamente añadir un else debajo del if!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aprovecho esta pregunta para comentar una característica *bastante rara* de Python, y es que los bucles `for` pueden tener una cláusula `else`.

Es una característica poco usada y que casi me atrevería a desaconsejar, porque hace el programa más ilegible y puede además inducir a confusiones en principiantes. Pese a todo la explico por si alguna vez te la encuentras por ahí, que sepas qué hace, y porque en este caso particular encaja muy bien con el código que tienes escrito.

La sintaxis de un `for/else` es así:

```
for elemento in iterable:
   # Instrucciones del for
   # entre las cuales puede aparecer break
else:
   # Instrucciones que se ejecutarán SOLO SI NO SE HIZO BREAK
```

Así, en tu caso, si detectas que un carácter es oclusivo, metes la palabra en la lista `si` y haces `break`. Pero si el bucle `for caracter in palabra` finaliza *sin que se haya hecho el break*, entonces la palabra debe ir a la lista `no`. Por tanto, usando la sintaxis recién explicada:

```
for palabra in claves:
    for caracter in palabra:
        if caracter in oclusivas:
            print(palabra,"--->",caracter)
            si.append(palabra)
            break
    else:
        no.append(palabra)
```

Answer (score 4):

No soy experto en python pero te faltan algunos pasos
primero el break lo mas probable que este saltándose la palabra y no el carácter así que si deje que continuara su loop pero si la palabra ya fue agregada al array `si` este no lo agrega de nuevo.

Segundo si la palabra no contiene ninguna letra en ningún momento lo estas agregando a la lista no. Para agregarlo despues de revisar todos los caracteres, pregunto si la palabra fue agregada a la lista `si`, si esta no lo agrego a ese array por defento se va a al array de no.

```
oclusivas = ["p","t","k","b","d","g"]
claves = ["zka","ze","apapk"]
si=[]
no=[]
for palabra in claves:
    for caracter in palabra:
        if caracter in oclusivas and palabra not in si:
            print(palabra,"--->",caracter)
            si.append(palabra)
            continue
    if palabra not in si: 
        no.append(palabra)
print("si: ",si)
print("no: ",no)
```

El código quedaría algo así. Como mencione anteriormente yo también estoy aprendiendo y este código puede ser mucho mas optimizado pero espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

En python cuando compruebas si un elemento **NO** está en una lista, se utiliza `not in`, no una comparación a `False`, dicho eso, aquí te dejo el código arreglado:

```
oclusivas = ["p","t","k","b","d","g"]
claves = ["zka","ze","apapk"]
si=[]
no=[]
for palabra in claves:
    for caracter in palabra:
        if caracter in oclusivas:
            print(palabra,"--->",caracter)
            si.append(palabra)
            break
        # Este else sería igual que -> if caracter not in oclusivas:
        else: # Con un else evitamos hacer otra comprobación igual
            no.append(palabra)
print("si: ",si)
```

Dicho esto, si necesitas comparar caracter a caracter... no te valdría la manera en que lo estás haciendo, ya que te aparecerá varias veces cada palabra en la lista `no`, una por cada letra que tenga la palabra. Te recomiendo hacer una función que devuelva true o false y la utilices para sustituir ese segundo bucle